# Tomcat 7 web-services, where should i put my image folder and how can i get my images?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

My project structure look like this:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enxfr.png)
I would like to return a base 64 image took directly from my images folder (in this case, BLUE-CAM1.png).

there is the code where i try to return the image:

```
@GET @Path("getImage")
public String displayImage()
{
    BufferedImage image;
    try {
         image = ImageIO.read(new File("/images/BLUE-CAM1.png"));

        return image.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "nothing";
}
```

But i got this error:

```
 javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

Where should I put the image folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the image of your project structure, however, servlet containers will serve resources stored in the META-INF/resources folder automatically, so if you packaged up your images up in your jar file in this location (eg. META-INF/resources/images/BLUE-CAM1.png), then from a browser, you should be able to access the image without the need to create a rest controller method like you have above...

```
http(s)://<host>:<port>/<contextPath>/images/BLUE-CAM1.png
```